# How to open ports on Windows firewall through batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, port, firewall

Is there any way within a batch file to open up specific ports on Windows through a batch file? It would be nice to have the installer do this for our server application rather than having the user manually do it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [netsh.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). A **very** simple batch file that takes a port argument:

```
@echo off
rem -- open port (first argument passed to batch script)
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port %1" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=%1 remoteip=10.15.97.0/24,10.17.0.0/16
```

Comment: Note that the process launching netsh (or whatever launches netsh, like your batch file for example) needs admin privledges to make port exceptions. Your installer can usually handle this at install-time depending on if the installer is running with admin privledges or not.

Answer (score 15):

This is an extension of solution provided by @Kevin Richardson. 
Note that "netsh advfirewall add rule" command will create a new rule with the same name every time you run the same command. The script below helps to prevent it

```
ECHO OFF
set PORT=8081
set RULE_NAME="Open Port %PORT%"

netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=%RULE_NAME% >nul
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    rem Rule %RULE_NAME% already exists.
    echo Hey, you already got a out rule by that name, you cannot put another one in!
) else (
    echo Rule %RULE_NAME% does not exist. Creating...
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=%RULE_NAME% dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=%PORT%
)
```

Comment: I have tried your solution (but with replacing the %RULENAME% with %RULE_NAME% in the echoes...) and it works as expected, thanks!

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful